# To prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (4,\pi)} x^2\sin \frac {y}{8}=\frac {8}{\sqrt 2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (4,\pi)} x^2\sin \frac {y}{8}=\frac {8}{\sqrt 2}$$
My attempt:

I have to prove $|x^2\sin\frac {y}{8}-\frac {8}{\sqrt 2}|\lt \epsilon$ when $|x-4|\lt \delta $ and $|y- \pi|\lt\delta$

So,
$$4-\delta\lt x\lt4+\delta$$
 $$16+\delta^2-8\delta\lt x^2 \lt16+\delta^2+8\delta$$
$$\pi-\delta\lt y\lt \pi+\delta$$
$$\sin\frac {\pi-\delta}{8}\lt \sin(\frac {y}{8}) \lt \sin\frac {\pi+\delta}{8}$$
But I got stuck after this.Should I multiply the two inequalities?How will I proceed after that?

Comment: Multiply last inequality to $x^2$ (for small enough $\delta$)  then less $\frac {8}{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: The idea is to make $\left| x^2 \sin \frac{y}{8} - \frac{8}{\sqrt{2}} \right|$ look like $\sqrt{(x-4)^2 + (y-\pi)^2}$.

Comment: A helpful inequality when dealing with products is Young's inequality: $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy$.