# Limit epsilon delta proof

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

How to prove the following with epsilon delta method
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (4,\pi)} x^{2} \sin \frac{y}{8} = 8 \sqrt{2}$$

P.S. This question is already asked in this forum but it has no solution.  Please provide an idea on how to go about this problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You stated the question was already asked, but had no solution. Please edit your question text to provide a link to this other question. Thanks.

Comment: Was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522475/to-prove-lim-x-y-to-4-pi-x2-sin-frac-y8-frac-8-sqrt-2) the one you found?

Comment: Actually, the limit is not $8 \sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the product $f(x)⋅g(y)$, of two continuous functions $f,g$, for any given $ϵ<1$ select $δ$ so that for $|x-x_0|<δ$, $|y-y_0|<δ$ you get $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<ϵ/M$, $|g(y)-g(y_0)|<ϵ/M$ with some $M\ge1$ that will depend on $x_0,y_0$ and $ϵ$. Then
\begin{align}
|f(x)⋅g(y)-f(x_0)⋅g(y_0)|
&\le |f(x)|\cdot |g(y)-g(y_0)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|\cdot|g(y_0)|\\
&< (|f(x_0)|+ϵ+|g(y_0)|)\cdotϵ/M
\end{align}
Thus with selecting $M=\max(1,|f(x_0)|+|g(y_0)|+ϵ)$ this inequality chain will indeed satisfy the continuity definition.

---

This proves that 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x)g(y)=f(x_0)g(y_0).
$$
To complete the task, you now only need to (confirm that the square and sine are continuous and) insert the limit point to evaluate
$$
4^2\sin\frac\pi8=8\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}.
$$

Comment: Is it rigorous to use the same $\delta$ for both $|x-x_0|$ and $|y-y_0|$?

Comment: Yes, for instance if $d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))=\max(|x-x_0|,|y-y_0|)$, which is one of the more convenient distances on the plane. And certainly, if $\sqrt{|x-x_0|^2+|y-y_0|^2}<δ$, then also $\max(|x-x_0|,|y-y_0|)<δ$. // Or, in a second interpretation of this comment, consider that from a finite number of positive numbers you can always take the minimum, which will also be a positive number.